# Change tabs on Windows when using Fusion?

Tags: mac, windows, vmware

I was wondering if it is possible to switch tabs while in Windows using Fusion (i.e like how you would alt/tab in general on a Windows machine). So far it only switches back to the Mac side, so I was curious if I could make tabbing into other applications/windows in Fusion easier.

Comment: 'switches back to the Mac side' doesn't add up. When you're running in Boot Camp Windows, there's no 'Mac side' running.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I press tab+command, it goes back to the mac window. (There is safari, finder, and VMFUSION (I don't own a mac, so I have limited knowledge of how any of this stuff works).

Comment: Then you're using Fusion, not Boot Camp. Boot Camp boots exclusively to native Windows, Fusion is a virtual machine. I don't know how Fusion works compared to Parallels - the other brand of virtual machine - but in Parallels alt/tab works fine to swap between Windows processes, Cmd/Tab swaps between Mac processes, of which the VM is one.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought they were the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard combo on your Mac keyboard is  option + tab.